# How to add array of tags with ng-tags-input?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, ng-tags-input

I have an input of ng-tags-input with autocomplete. 
The autocomplete can show "users", "organisations" and "Mailing lists" (which contains an array of users and another array of organisations).

When I click on a user in the autocompletion, a user tag is created. 
When I click on an organisation in the autocompletion, an organisation tag is created. 
But when I click on a Mailing List in the autocompletion, I would like to add every users and every organisations contained in the mailing list as individual tags. I've searched many ways to do this but I can't figure out how to do this last point...

ng-tags-input propose the function $removeTag to remove a tag but I haven't found any function to add a tag with Javascript. 
I would be very grateful if anybody would have any clue! 
Thanks!

Comment: Please type, or copy/paste, a minimal example of your current code so we can help you. Who knows... you may find your answer as you start typing it.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add tags into ng-tags-input. Which translates to - I want to mutate the model bound to ng-tags-input. Or, I want to push elements inside the array of objects which contains the tags. So you basically want to push objects into the model bound to your ng-tags-input directive.

```
<tags-input ng-model="tagsModel" >
```

You need to attach handler to the event when a suggestion is selected from the list. I guess the autocomplete feature itself allows you to bind a scope function to it.
Then, If it is the type 'Mailing List', then iterate through each element of selected array, contruct the tags (basically an object of form { text: 'value'} ) and push it into your tagsModel.

Hope it helps. If you attach a plnkr, I would be able to better answer this.